# Last name typo on a Saudia Airlines flight from Bangalore BLR to Los Angeles LAX

Tags: indian-citizens, los-angeles, bangalore, saudi-airlines

I have my last name typed in wrongly(xxx Tumakuru instead of xxx yyy Tumkur)  while I was booking the ticket on Saudia for my trip on OCt 1, 2017 from BLR to LAX. 
The reason being my passport was recently received from a Visa stamping and the sticker on the back of the passport had Tumakuru written on it, I saw that and used it. Tumakuru is how it's spelled on my passport for my place of birth but my last name on passport has Tumkur (they both mean the place name). Also while booking the ticket on Saudia I couldn't add the second part in my first name as the system showed an error due to spaces in first name so I skipped adding the second word.

Has anyone had issues travelling from Bangalore with a slightly misspelled name and a missing middle name on the boarding pass but all these present on the passport?

Thx...

Answer (score 2):

Missing middle names are mostly irrelevant, don’t worry about that part.

You should worry about the misspelled last name; depending on the agent at check-in, you might not be allowed to board. You may be able to convince him/her that it is a simple misspelling, but then maybe not. I recommend you call the airline *now*, explain the issue, and have them correct the name on the booking.

Most airlines do not allow name changes on a ticket, but the point behind it is that they do not allow to transfer the ticket *to a different traveller*. Name *corrections* are typically accepted, especially if they happen far in advance of the flight - not so good last minute. So call *soon*.

Note that for flights to the US, they have to submit a list of names on the flight upfront to the US government (some days ahead), and they will be checked against the no-fly lists (and other stuff). After they submit it, you can’t change the name for sure (otherwise, this would be a way to bypass the no-fly list...), and you must have a passport with an exact match.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I spoke to the airline and they said they can do it at a steep cost. Yikes! But they did say that minor spelling mistakes are generally fine but then again it depends on the immigration at Bangalore. Also the airlines said they can attach a sort of comment/ note/remark on the ticket to indicate the actual name on the passport though the boarding pass a different spelling for last name--I believe this is the database you talk about. I am trying to reach on some of their support emails. I ll update how it goes.

Comment: I find it so disappointing when people take advantage of a received answer and do not even accept it nor upvote it - I am not here to judge but not the people I want in my life.